# How to set the PATH for PHP in a different directory on my Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

I did some research on how to do this and this is what I found.  I need to alter this block of code:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
<key>PATH</key>
<string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin</ string>
</dict>
```

in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

I need to set Apache to point to `/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini`.  How do I alter the string in the above code so it points PHP to the correct installation of PHP.  It's now where Homebrew put it because PHP already existed on my hard drive.

Comment: The system path rarely has much to do with which PHP apache loads - The path is for command-line PHP. apache will be loading php as a module, which is a .so file. You need to modify the location Apache is looking for php's .so file, and that'll be somewhere in apache's .conf file(s).

Answer (score 2):

Set it as follows:

```
<string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin</ string>
```

You new php directory must be at beginning so it is picked first.

As per [**this**](http://blog.arnaudlafon.com/Blog/Homebrew-repository-dedicated-to-PHP-and-PHP-5.3.10-installation), you should add the following:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php/5.4/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file and restart apache.

Comment: I did that and restarted Apache but my PHPinfo file still says 5.3.15

Comment: The file is in my localhost directory.  Also, my CLI says 5.3.15.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, see the article I linked it shows an alternative way to what you are doing.

Comment: OK thanks.  I tried your suggestion and it broke my localhost and my CLI remains at 5.3.15.  I'll read the article.